# Terminal window terminates after double click or any text selection

Tags: 12.10, command-line

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10. After a while the following problem appeared:
Whenever I use mouse to select any text in the terminal (by double clicking or by clicking at one end of a text and highlighting to the other end, the terminal would be closed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a terminal you should use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to **Copy** the selected text from the terminal and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to **paste** some text to the terminal.

As <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>in terminal are used to stop any running processes.

Hope it helps you.. Reply for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think you misunderstood the problem. I can't use mouse to select any text in the terminal, neither by double click nor by click at one end of text and highlighting to the other end.

Comment: Be specific and clear to your question. I suggest you to edit your question and add the comment you did.